# How to stub writing to file in minitest

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking, minitest

I have the following piece of code which I want to test using minitest:

```rb
def write(text, fname)
  File.open(fname, 'w') do |f|
    f << text
  end  
end
```

I wanted to mock the file using StringIO, so I did:

```
class TestWrite << Minitest::Test
  def test_write
    # arrange
    m_file = StringIO.new
    mock_open = Minitest::Mock.new
    mock_open.expect :call, m_file, ['fname', 'w']

    # act
    File.stub :open, mock_open do
      write('hello!', 'fname')
    end

    # assert
    mock_open.verify  # successful assert!    
    assert_equal 'hello!', m_file.string  # failure :(
  end
```

The second assert seem to fail because the code inside the `do` block of `File.open` never runs. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?